# java Combo Auto Complete search data work smoothly with jdk 9 but is slow with jdk 8

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

My question is why same class work fine quickly without any late with jdk 9, but is take some time with jdk 8.
Using jdk 9 and higher will solve my problem for autocomplete search to run smoothly, but then I will face bigger problem is my reports jrxml files will not work with jdk higher than 8.
Any suggestion to make this code work smoothly with jdk 8?
Here is same code for both jdk 9 and 8.
thanks in advance
i upload video to YouTube
here is a link
https://youtu.be/huBr-f-dyCE

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

public class ComboAutoComplete1 extends PlainDocument {
    JComboBox comboBox;
    ComboBoxModel model;
    JTextComponent editor;
    
    // flag to indicate if setSelectedItem has been called
    // subsequent calls to remove/insertString should be ignored
    boolean selecting=false;
    boolean hidePopupOnFocusLoss;
    boolean hitBackspace=false;
    boolean hitBackspaceOnSelection;
    
    KeyListener editorKeyListener;
    FocusListener editorFocusListener;
    
    public ComboAutoComplete1(final JComboBox comboBox) {
       
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
        
        model = comboBox.getModel();
        comboBox.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (!selecting) highlightCompletedText(0);
        });
        comboBox.addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("editor")) configureEditor((ComboBoxEditor) e.getNewValue());
            if (e.getPropertyName().equals("model")) model = (ComboBoxModel) e.getNewValue();
        });
        editorKeyListener = new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.isDisplayable()) comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
                hitBackspace=false;
                switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
                    // determine if the pressed key is backspace (needed by the remove method)
                    case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE : hitBackspace=true;
                    hitBackspaceOnSelection=editor.getSelectionStart()!=editor.getSelectionEnd();
                    break;
                    // ignore delete key
                    case KeyEvent.VK_DELETE : e.consume();
                    comboBox.getToolkit().beep();
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt){
               
          }
        });
        
        // Bug 5100422 on Java 1.5: Editable JComboBox won't hide popup when tabbing out
        hidePopupOnFocusLoss=System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.5");
        // Highlight whole text when gaining focus
        editorFocusListener = new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                highlightCompletedText(0);
            }
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // Workaround for Bug 5100422 - Hide Popup on focus loss
                if (hidePopupOnFocusLoss) comboBox.setPopupVisible(false);
            }
        };
        configureEditor(comboBox.getEditor());
        // Handle initially selected object
        Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if (selected!=null) setText(selected.toString());
        highlightCompletedText(0);
    }
    
    
    public static void enable(JComboBox comboBox, String str) {
        // has to be editable
        comboBox.setEditable(true);        
        // change the editor's document
        new ComboAutoComplete1(comboBox);
    }
    
    void configureEditor(ComboBoxEditor newEditor) {
        if (editor != null) {
            editor.removeKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
            editor.removeFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
        }
        
        if (newEditor != null) {
            editor = (JTextComponent) newEditor.getEditorComponent();
            editor.addKeyListener(editorKeyListener);
            editor.addFocusListener(editorFocusListener);
            editor.setDocument(this);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void remove(int offs, int len) throws BadLocationException {
        // return immediately when selecting an item
        if (selecting) return;
        if (hitBackspace) {
            // user hit backspace => move the selection backwards
            // old item keeps being selected
            if (offs>0) {
                if (hitBackspaceOnSelection) offs--;
            } else {
                // User hit backspace with the cursor positioned on the start => beep
                comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); // when available use: UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(comboBox);
            }
            highlightCompletedText(offs);
        } else {
            super.remove(offs, len);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
        // return immediately when selecting an item
        if (selecting) return;
        // insert the string into the document
        super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        // lookup and select a matching item
        Object item = lookupItem(getText(0, getLength()));
        if (item != null) {
            setSelectedItem(item);
        } else {
            // keep old item selected if there is no match
            item = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
            // imitate no insert (later on offs will be incremented by str.length(): selection won't move forward)
            offs = offs-str.length();
            // provide feedback to the user that his input has been received but can not be accepted
            comboBox.getToolkit().beep(); // when available use: UIManager.getLookAndFeel().provideErrorFeedback(comboBox);
        }
        setText(item.toString());
        // select the completed part
        highlightCompletedText(offs+str.length());
    }
    
    private void setText(String text) {
        try {
            // remove all text and insert the completed string
            super.remove(0, getLength());
            super.insertString(0, text, null);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
        }
    }
    
    private void highlightCompletedText(int start) {
        editor.setCaretPosition(getLength());
        editor.moveCaretPosition(start);
    }
    
    private void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        selecting = true;
        model.setSelectedItem(item);
        selecting = false;
    }
    
    private Object lookupItem(String pattern) {
        Object selectedItem = model.getSelectedItem();
        // only search for a different item if the currently selected does not match
        if (selectedItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(selectedItem.toString(), pattern)) {
            return selectedItem;
        } else {
            // iterate over all items
            for (int i=0, n=model.getSize(); i < n; i++) {
                Object currentItem = model.getElementAt(i);
                // current item starts with the pattern?
                if (currentItem != null && startsWithIgnoreCase(currentItem.toString(), pattern)) {
                    return currentItem;
                }
            }
        }
        // no item starts with the pattern => return null
        return null;
    }
    
    // checks if str1 starts with str2 - ignores case
    private boolean startsWithIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.toUpperCase().startsWith(str2.toUpperCase());
    }
    
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // the combo box (add/modify items if you like to)
        final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        enable(comboBox,"");

        // create and show a window containing the combo box
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
        frame.pack(); frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: We don’t have your database, so we can’t run your program and we can’t reproduce your problem.  Create a smaller copy of your program without the database parts, and show us that code, so we can run it ourselves.

Comment: you can take a look again as you suggested i updated code and removed database part from it thanks for response